# Foundation 5 - modifying top-bar links to have a border-bottom with SASS

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, border, navbar

I'm working on a Foundation 5 site and need to customize the `.top-bar` navigation menu. I am using the `SASS` version of Foundation.

I'm having difficulty modifying the active and hover styles for the menu links using SASS. I've changed their colors, however I want to add a `border-bottom` to the links to indicate active/hover state.

By default, Foundation uses background color for indicating active/hover, and I'm not sure exactly where I need to edit to add border-bottom. As I currently have it, the border is far too low, I need it to be underneath the text.

**Currently Looks like this:**

[image]

**Need it to look like this with `border-bottom` on :**

[image]

**current styles in `_settings.scss`:**

```
$topbar-bg-color: $white;
$topbar-bg: $topbar-bg-color;

// Height and margin
$topbar-height: rem-calc(65);


// Set the link colors and styles for top-level nav
$topbar-link-color: $asc-darkgray;
$topbar-link-color-hover: $lesson-orange;
$topbar-link-color-active: $lesson-orange;
$topbar-link-color-active-hover: $white;
$topbar-link-bg: $white;
$topbar-link-bg-color-hover: $white;
$topbar-link-bg-hover: $white;
$topbar-link-bg-active: $white;
$topbar-link-text-transform: uppercase;


// Divider Styles
$topbar-divider-border-bottom: solid 1px  scale-color($asc-lightgray, $lightness: 13%);
$topbar-divider-border-top: solid 1px scale-color($asc-lightgray, $lightness: -50%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `<a>` tags in the top-bar are set with a `line-height` equal to the height of the top-bar to ensure they are aligned to the middle.

If you want to use border bottom on a menu link and still have it vertically aligned to the middle of the top-bar you just need to span the link text:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="link-border-bottom">border bottom link</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

and give your `<span>` an class with `border-bottom` (on `:hover` if you want):

```
.link-border-bottom {
   &:hover {
     border-bottom: 1px solid orange; 
   }
}
```

or if you want the active link to be underlined:

```
.active { 
  .link-border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange; 
  }
}
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AJLprTOxSVFGD2h5Ue30?p=preview) using vanilla CSS.

Comment: D'oh, sometimes the simplest answers truly are the best :) I was approaching this by trying to modify the pre-existing foundation stylings and for whatever reason it never occurred to me to just simply wrap them with a new element. Thanks for providing a voice of reason :-)

Comment: Nice pun! Glad to have helped.